# Creating starred song playlist on iPhone without going to the computer

Tags: itunes

Seems like one cannot create playlist of starred songs on your iPhone without going it through iTunes on your computer. Can someone verify this please? Or is there some way to do it on the phone itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create a smart playlist on the iPhone itself. You have to use iTunes for that.

I think that’s really stupid.

Comment: Yep, I would agree it to be stupid. Especially considering apple's promotion of recent iOS devices not needing tethering to computer for even critical tasks like an OS upgrade.